# Swift xcode error: load controller is not allowed and autoresize not equal to views window

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Screenshot of what I'm trying to create: [image: screen layout]

NOTE: There's no need to look at the code below if you decide to run the project because all the classes I posted below are inside the dropbox zipped project file.

Each of the squares on the bottom selects a different color and there's an invisible square that selects the type of shape off to the right of the green one. After the user selects one of these shapes, the user will be able to draw in a certain part of the screen.

Entire project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9pr0wo0j74iw4a/XcodeSwiftProject99999.zip?dl=0

If you run the project, create an account, then click sign in, then click one of the rows, then click on one of the colored boxes (red and green squares) the app will crash and get the following error message:

```
2016-03-11 17:06:43.580 finalProject2[11487:1058358] <UIView: 0x7faba1677710; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7faba1658d90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faba16563f0>>'s window is not equal to <finalProject2.RowTableViewController: 0x7faba165a3c0>'s view's window!

File slot 1

File slot 2

File slot 3

File slot 4

File slot 5

File slot 6

File slot 7

File slot 8

File slot 9

File slot 10

File slot 11

File slot 12

2016-03-11 17:06:44.746 finalProject2[11487:1058358] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7faba16b7d60>)
```

MainProject scene class:

```
import UIKit



weak var FirstFileNameTextField: UILabel!

enum ShapeType: String

{

    case Line = "Line"

    case Ellipse = "Ellipse"

    case Rectangle = "Rectangle"

    case FilledEllipse = "Filled Ellipse"

    case FilledRectangle = "Filled Rectangle"

    case Scribble = "Scribble"

}

 let shapes: [ShapeType] = [ .Line, .Ellipse, .Rectangle, .FilledEllipse, .FilledRectangle, .Scribble ]



class MainProjectScene: UIViewController

{

     var row: Row?







    @IBAction func PressedSaveAs(sender: UIButton) //this is the save as function that I would like to know how to change



    {



        //1. Create the alert controller.



        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name/rename your file:", message: "Enter a filename to name/rename and save your file", preferredStyle: .Alert)



        //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.



        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in



            textField.text = "Your file name"

        })



        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler:

            {

                (action) -> Void in

                let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

                print("Text field: \(textField.text)")

                // rows.cell.textLabel?.text = textField.text

                CurrentFileName = textField.text!

                rows[IndexPath.row].FileName = textField.text!

                rows[IndexPath.row].UserText = self.TextUserScrollEdit.text!



        }))



        // 4. Present the alert.

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)





      //  rows[indexPath.row].FileName = rows.cell.textLabel?.text



       // rows[i] = textField.text



               // if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MainProjectScene {



              //  if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {



              //  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {



               // detailViewController.row = rows[indexPath.row]



    }





    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)

    {



        if let r = row

        {



            row!.FileName = r.FileName



            row!.QuartzImage = r.QuartzImage



            row!.UserText = r.UserText

            rows[IndexPath.row].UserText = self.TextUserScrollEdit.text!        }

    }





    override func  viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        TextUserScrollEdit.text = rows[IndexPath.row].UserText

        // FacebookButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapFacebook", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var TextUserScrollEdit: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var NewFileButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TwoDQuartzButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var YouTubeButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TwitterButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var OpenFileButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var SnapChatButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var FacebookButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedTwoDQuartzButton(sender: UIButton) {



    }



    @IBAction func PressedSnapchatButton(sender: UIButton){



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.snapchat.com/")!)



    }



    @IBAction func PressedYouTubeButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/")!)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var InstagramButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedFacebookButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.facebook.com")!)



    }

    @IBAction func PressedInstagramButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/")!)



    }



    @IBAction func PressedTwitterButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/")!)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var SaveAsButton: UIButton!













      // @IBOutlet weak var shapeButton: ShapeButton!



    @IBOutlet weak var canvas: CanvasView!



        @IBOutlet var colorButtons: [UIButton]!



    @IBOutlet weak var shapeButton: ShapeButton!



        @IBAction func selectColor(sender: UIButton) {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0,

                usingSpringWithDamping: CGFloat(0.25),

                initialSpringVelocity: CGFloat(0.25),

                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

                    for button in self.colorButtons {

                        button.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - 58

                    }

                    sender.frame.origin.y -= 20

                }, completion: nil)

            canvas.color = sender.backgroundColor!

            shapeButton.color = sender.backgroundColor!

        }



        @IBAction func selectShape(sender: ShapeButton) {

            let title = "Select Shape"

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)



            for shape in shapes {

                let action = UIAlertAction(title: shape.rawValue, style: .Default) { action in

                    sender.shape = shape

                    self.canvas.shape = shape

                }

                alertController.addAction(action)

            }

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }



}
```

ShapeButton class:

```
import UIKit





class ShapeButton: UIButton {





    let shapes: [ShapeType] = [ .Line, .Ellipse, .Rectangle, .FilledEllipse, .FilledRectangle, .Scribble ]



    var shape: ShapeType = .Line {

        didSet {

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor() {

        didSet {

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.

    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Drawing code

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2)



        let x1: CGFloat = 5

        let y1: CGFloat = 5

        let x2: CGFloat = frame.width - 5

        let y2: CGFloat = frame.height - 5

        let rect = CGRect(x: x1, y: y1 + 5, width: frame.width - 10, height: frame.height - 20)

        switch shape {

        case .Line:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1, y1)

            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x2, y2)

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        case .Ellipse:

            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .Rectangle:

            CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledEllipse:

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledRectangle:

            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        case .Scribble:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1, y1)

            CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,

                x1 + 80, y1 - 10,           // the 1st control point

                x2 - 80, y2 + 10,           // the 2nd control point

                x2, y2)           // the end point

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        }

    }





}
```

Canvas view class:

```
import UIKit



/*

    This program is for Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2

*/





class CanvasView: UIView {





    var shape: ShapeType = .Line

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    var first :CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var last  :CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var points: [CGPoint] = []



    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.

    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Drawing code

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)



        let rect = CGRect(x: first.x, y: first.y, width: last.x - first.x, height: last.y - first.y)

        switch shape {

        case .Line:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y)

            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, last.x, last.y)

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        case .Ellipse:

            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .Rectangle:

            CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledEllipse:

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledRectangle:

            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        case .Scribble:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y)

            for p in points {

                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p.x, p.y)

            }

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        }

    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            first = touch.locationInView(self)

            last = first

            points.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(first)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            last = touch.locationInView(self)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(last)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            last = touch.locationInView(self)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(last)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }




}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the line that is crashing and relevant associated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, go to `MainProjectScene` and right click on `CanvasView`.

**You'll have two referencing outlets to `CanvasView`.**

Remove both the referencing outlets. Now select the `CanvasView` again and go to the identity inspector and make sure the class of the view is `CanvasView`

[image]

Keep your main storyboard and `MainProjectScene` and link your `CanvasView` to the view in your storyboard like this

[image]

That fixed the issue.

I'll just shed you some insight on the problem you just faced. You might have created a view outlet first in the code and linked it and then deleted it. Then again you must have created it and linked it. After doing this you'll have 2 referencing outlets on your view. You need to remove the one you just deleted or the code will crash.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much. You are the best.